# Filter data using daterange with checkbox and join table

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to filter data with date range and checkbox. It works for checkbox but i got this error where i add some queries for date range.

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BMJSGCR\1\dt_rtrend1.php on line 51
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\BMJSGCR\1\dt_rtrend1.php on line 58

Is it possible to use filter daterange ? because i use type data datetime in database.

here's my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['chk'])) {
    $defect_query = "";
    foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) {
        $defect_query = $defect_query . ", COUNT(CASE t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHEN " . $data . " THEN t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_NAME END) AS `" . $data . "`";
    }

    //$machine        = $_POST['machine'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    //$grade      = $_POST['grade'];
    $chk = $_POST['chk'];
    ?>

    <thead>
    <th class="text-center" >Date Process</th>
    <?php
    foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) {
        $get_defect_name = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `t_defect_class` WHERE `DEFECT_CLASS_ID` = $data");
        $defect_name_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_defect_name);
        ?>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo $defect_name_table['DEFECT_CLASS_NAME']; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $modal = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME" . $defect_query . " FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($modal);

    if ($count == "0") {
        ?>
        <td class="text-center">NOT FOUND</td>
        <?php
    } else {

        while ($defect = mysqli_fetch_array($modal)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $defect['PROCESS_TIME']; ?></td>
                <?php foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) { ?>
                    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $defect[$data]; ?></td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>


            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

thank you

Comment: is `DEFECT_CLASS_ID` an integer value?

Comment: yes, it's integer

Comment: great, I'll continue my review of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved!, Thanks everyone!.
here's my code

```
if (isset($_POST['chk'])){
  $defect_query = "";
  foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) {
    $defect_query = $defect_query.", COUNT(CASE t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHEN ".$data." THEN t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_NAME END) AS `".$data."`";
  }

  if (isset($_POST['machine'])) {
    $machine        = $_POST['machine'];
  }
  $start_date   = $_POST['start_date'];
  $end_date     = $_POST['end_date'];
  // echo "<script>alert('".$start_date." - ".$end_date."')</script>";
  if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
    $grade      = $_POST['grade'];
  }
  $chk          = $_POST['chk'];




?>

    <thead>
      <th class="text-center" >Date Process</th>
      <?php
        foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) {
          $get_defect_name = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `t_defect_class` WHERE `DEFECT_CLASS_ID` = $data");
          $defect_name_table = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_defect_name);
        ?>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo $defect_name_table['DEFECT_CLASS_NAME']; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
    </thead>
<?php




  if (isset($_POST['grade']) && isset($_POST['machine'])) {
    $modal=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME".$defect_query." FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHERE t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' AND t_name_file.MACHINE_ID = '".$machine."' AND t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID = '".$grade."' GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");
  } else if (isset($_POST['machine']) && !isset($_POST['grade'])) {
    $modal=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME".$defect_query." FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHERE t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' AND t_name_file.MACHINE_ID = '".$machine."' GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");
  } else if (isset($_POST['grade']) && !isset($_POST['machine'])) {
    $modal=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME".$defect_query." FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHERE t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' AND t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID = '".$grade."' GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");
  } else {
    $modal=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME".$defect_query." FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHERE t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");
  }
  // echo "<script>alert(\"SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME".$defect_query." FROM t_transaction INNER JOIN t_name_file ON t_transaction.NAMEFILE_ID=t_name_file.NAMEFILE_ID INNER JOIN t_defect_class ON t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID=t_defect_class.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHERE t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '".$start_date."' AND '".$end_date."' AND t_name_file.MACHINE_ID = '".$machine."' AND t_name_file.GRADE = '".$grade."' GROUP BY t_transaction.DEFECT_CLASS_ID, t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME\")</script>";
  $no = 0;
  while($defect=mysqli_fetch_array($modal)){
  $no++;

?>
  <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><?php echo $defect['PROCESS_TIME']; ?></td>
      <?php foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $id => $data) { ?>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo  $defect[$data]; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
  </tr>


<?php 
} 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have several security and efficiency concerns as I review your snippet, but to focus on the question asked, the issue seems to be that you have a rogue `WHERE` at the end of `$modal` that will surely be causing an issue.

If this doesn't alleviate the error, you should improve your question to include the exact error message that is generated.

---

And I've discovered that there is no `,` before the third condition in your GROUP BY clause.

---

And while I really wish I could test my snippet before posting it here, I think script will offer improved security, stability, efficiency, and readability.  (Of course, no guarantees that it is bug-free)

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['chk']
    || empty($_POST['start_date'])
    || empty($_POST['end_date'])
    || !is_array($_POST['chk'])
    || date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['start_date'])) !== $_POST['start_date']
    || date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['end_date'])) !== $_POST['end_date']) {
    echo "Missing/Invalid Submission Data";
} else {  // all expected submission data is present and sufficiently valid
    $defect_select_ext = "";
    foreach ($_POST['chk'] as &$data) {
        $data = (int)$data; // for security
        $defect_select_ext .= ", COUNT(CASE a.DEFECT_CLASS_ID WHEN $data THEN c.DEFECT_CLASS_NAME END) AS `$data`";
    }
    // I assume you are already connected...
    // avoid iterated queries but maintain order
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DEFECT_CLASS_NAME FROM t_defect_class WHERE DEFECT_CLASS_ID IN (" . implode(',', $_POST['chk']) . ") ORDER BY FIELD(DEFECT_CLASS_ID," . implode(',', $_POST['chk']) . ")")) {
        echo "Syntax Error While Retrieving DEFECT CLASS NAMES";
    } else {
        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Date Process</th>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo "<th class=\"text-center\">{$row['DEFECT_CLASS_NAME']}</th>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME" . $defect_select_ext . "
                      FROM t_transaction a
                      INNER JOIN t_name_file b ON a.NAMEFILE_ID = b.NAMEFILE_ID
                      INNER JOIN t_defect_class c ON a.DEFECT_CLASS_ID = c.DEFECT_CLASS_ID
                      GROUP BY a.DEFECT_CLASS_ID,
                               b.PROCESS_TIME,
                               b.PROCESS_TIME BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
                      ORDER BY t_name_file.PROCESS_TIME");
            $colspan = sizeof($_POST['chk']) + 1;
            if (!$modal = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
                echo "<tr><td colspan=\"$colspan\" class=\"text-center\">Syntax Error @ Master Query</td></tr>";
            } elseif (!mysqli_num_rows($modal)) {
                echo "<tr><td colspan=\"$colspan\" class=\"text-center\">NOT FOUND</td></tr>";
            } else {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($modal)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td class=\"text-center\">{$row['PROCESS_TIME']}</td>";
                        foreach ($_POST['chk'] as $data) {
                            echo "<td class=\"text-center\">{$row[$data]}</td>";
                        }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

p.s. I recommend that you keep your database table names and column names in all lowercase so that it is easier to differentiate your table/column names from the MYSQL KEYWORDS/FUNCTIONS.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Nanda did you have success when you added the comma?